# Updating system time in Visual Studio using .net(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How can I update the system time using Visual Studio with C#(.Net)??

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204936/set-time-programmatically-using-c

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
Process.Start("time", "12:00:00");
```

Comment: this depends on the regional setting