# updating system time in Visual Studio using C#(.Net)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a web service running that is returning a time. I want to update my system's time with the time that my service is returning . How can I do this in visual studio using C#?

**Edit:** Exact duplicate of: [Set time programmatically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204936/set-time-programmatically-using-c)

Comment: KInd of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516977/updating-system-time-in-visual-studio-using-netc?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you bothering to re-invent the wheel?

Windows already has a built in NTP/[time service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773013.aspx), that will sync the time with any of the [public time servers](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/WebHome) or a private one that [you create](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773061.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I would write a wrapper for the windows API SetSystemTime.  Something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

public struct SYSTEMTIME

{
public short wYear;

public short wMonth;

public short wDayOfWeek;

public short wDay;

public short wHour;

public short wMinute;

public short wSecond;

public short wMilliseconds;

}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]

public static extern bool SetSystemTime( [In] ref SYSTEMTIME st );
```

(Please note that I have not tested this, but it should get you started)