# Sync system time to domain controller using .NET code

Tags: c#, .net, windows, interop

I have time based tests to run that require changing the system time multiple times during the test.  I want to be able to resync the time to the domain controller time at the end of the test.  I there any way to do that using .NET code (C#).  I am changing the time using the p-invoke function found in:

[Set time programmatically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204936/set-time-programmatically-using-c)

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One easy way would be to launch a process and run the NET TIME command (copied from http://blogs.msdn.com/sanket/archive/2006/11/02/synchronizing-machine-time-with-domain-controller.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process netTime = new Process();

        netTime.StartInfo.FileName   = "NET.exe";
        netTime.StartInfo.Arguments = "TIME /domain:mydomainname /SET /Y";
        netTime.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. This is exactly what I was writing up, you just beat me to it. Nice one.

Comment: Should I see the command in the open window? It doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Can you please suggest something I can write to mydomainname?

Comment: @Fantom789 I guess time.windows.com would be good or time.nist.gov (but it is still not working for me

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the other answers:

You should seriously consider making the notion of "current time" somehow injectable into your system. Directly reading from the system clock is very problematic (even when running the app), precisely because it is global state.

Comment: That was definately my first option, to do something like in the following post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43711/whats-a-good-way-to-overwrite-datetime-now-during-testing

Unfortunately, I am working with a platform solution that does not give me access to doing such a thing.  It's either this, or not do regression testing, and I don't like the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the command line tool w32tm:

```
w32tm /resync
```

This is neither C# nor .NET, but it hopefully fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use **System.Diagnostics.Process** to run a **net time** command with the appropriate parameters to sync back to your DC.

Run this from a command prompt to see what I'm talking about:

```
net time /?
```

Comment: Soory for the double post, Justin beat me to it.