# Setting net time on C# program

Tags: c#

I am syncing date and time on my three computers on a network without internet.

I have a command on cmd  `net time \\PCNAME /set /y` seems working, now my problem is how will I execute this as a query on my C# program?

Comment: Have you tried `Process.Start`? `Process.Start(@" net time \PCNAME /set /y ")`

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472225/sync-system-time-to-domain-controller-using-net-code#1472290

Answer (score 1):

Easy :)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", @"net time \PCNAME /set /y");
```